# Login and Facebook integration issue in Android Application

Tags: android, facebook

I am facing a problem in facebook integration in android application.
The problem is that when I try to go to this activity and try to login to the `facebook` the following error appears on the logcat. I am using the `facebook android sdk`.

`10-19 14:58:58.273: DEBUG/Facebook-authorize(288): Login failed: com.facebook.android.DialogError: A secure connection could not be established.`

Will you please anyone help me out in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set uses permission in Android Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem due to phone's network signal. I too was getting the same problem. Log in using Facebook works perfectly when you get proper network signal on your mobile.